# How to Convert HTML Table to PDF and Save as PDF along with CSS - Client Side?

Tags: html-table, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

My requirement is Save HTML Table to PDF with CSS. And download as PDF file. I used jsPDF but not working in IE to convert HTML to PDF along with CSS. If any paid version or free version both will be fine for me.

Canvas approach will create the image of HTML Table and I want to use as original Table.

Appreciate reply!!!

Comment: any c# wkhtmltopdf wrapper can do the job. Also you can check phantomjs if you need modern HTML5 features (like flex/grid). BTW, questions like 'recommend library' are offtopic according to StackOverflow rules

Comment: Ok. I have changed my questions. I want to do PDF with client side code